# php image upload will not work

Tags: php

I have asked this question before I made changes to my code and my image upload is not working at all I have checked username password, and Root they are all correct. my code will not show any errors I dont know what to do anymore can someone please help me? I have changed my connection for security reasons

```
<?php 

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "torcdesi_jone45", "password", "torcdesi_amazing");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$query_image = 'INSERT INTO shirt_table (images3) 
                values( "' . $_FILES['file3']['name'] . '")';
?>
<?php

include("configur.php");
if($_POST) { 
    // $_FILES["file"]["error"] is HTTP File Upload variables $_FILES["file"] "file" is the name of input field you have in form tag.

     if ($_FILES["file3"]["error"] > 0) {
        // if there is error in file uploading 
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file3"]["error"] . "<br />";
    } else {
        // check if file already exit in "images" folder.
        if (file_exists("shirtimgs/" . $_FILES["file3"]["name"])) {
        } else { 
            //move_uploaded_file function will upload your image. 
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file3"]["tmp_name"],"shirtimgs/" . $_FILES["file3"]["name"]))
            {
                // If file has uploaded successfully, store its name in data base
                $query_image = "insert into shirt_table";

                if(mysqli_query($link, $query_image)) {
                    echo "Stored in: " . "shirtimgs/" . $_FILES["file3"]["name"];
                } else {   
                    echo'';
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: check for errors then

Comment: *"i have asked this question before"* - you mean this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41950688/image-name-will-not-upload-to-database - if so, it constitutes as a repost.

Comment: and I know what's missing, and rather quite simple really and error reporting and reading the manuals would have helped you here.

Comment: missing html form, I can go on you know but you've some missing stuff in the question which I can guess what "is" missing. But I won't be waving any magic wands here.

Comment: im very sorry how do i get error reporting?

Comment: *Waving my magic wand with a bit of magic...* http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php => `<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="__URL__" method="POST">` ----- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Thank you and your magic wand I appreciate  your help

Comment: I take it that it worked ;-) correct?

Comment: well, did it work or not? where are we with the question? I think it did; I posted my answer below.

Comment: Pity your bench checking is not as good as your ability to flag comments you dont like

Comment: This query makes no sence  `$query_image = "insert into shirt_table";` and is only one of the problems. I mentioned it on your other question, but you had the comment removed without paying any attention to it

Answer (score 2):

As I stated in comments, your form is missing a proper enctype to handle files.

This I know, since I saw [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41950688/image-name-will-not-upload-to-database) that did not contain it in the form.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="__URL__" method="POST">
```

As per the manual:

- http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php